# How to reset MacOS QGIS to defaults?

Tags: qgis

I can't find a way to clear away all imported QGIS styles, even completely removing all QGIS files, after new install - old styles are still there. Where to look?

Removing one by one is the only option from within the application, but there are hundreds that I have imported.

I found the "first run state" question, but that answer works for Windows, but how about MacOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS on Mac & *Nix also stores some information inside of a folder (invisible on Macs) inside of your home directory. The folder is located at ~/.qgis . You may need to delete one or more files from this folder.

You can access this folder in Finder by clicking the Go menu and choosing Go to Folder. Type in ~/.qgis and click Go.

Note: Backing up is also advised prior to making any changes.

Comment: See also OSX clean install instructions [here](http://press.underdiverwaterman.com/clean-install-of-qgis-in-osx/).

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting org.qgis.QGIS.plist in the Library/Preferences directory of your home directory. You might want to make a backup copy of it first just in case.

Comment: Nice, can someone with a Mac check this?

Comment: Nope, I removed all Qgis plist files from that location, Qgis now doesn't remember the recent file locations, but the Styles Manager still contains all the imported styles.